# is CHU locally finitely presentable?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I have a simple question, I think.  Is CHU, the category of CHU spaces, locally finitely presentable?

Comment: Looking at the definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_space it even seems to be an algebraic category?

Comment: This question has been essentially answered in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141360/lfp-property-for-dagger-symmetric-monoidal-categories-and-their-internal-categor

Comment: Yes, see Todd's comment on his answer.

Comment: I'm closing this, without any prejudice, just for the sake of tidying up.