# lfp property for dagger symmetric monoidal categories and their internal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, symmetric-monoidal-categories

We can define internal categories in a monoidal category like [this](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category+in+a+monoidal+category).  Let $C$ be a dagger symmetric monoidal category.  Will $C$ be locally finitely presentable?  Let $C_{int}$ be the category of internal categories in $C$.  Is $C_{int}$ locally finitely presentable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a [dagger-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dagger-category) $C$, we have $C^{op} \simeq C$. But the only time that a category $C$ and its opposite can both be locally finitely presentable is when $C$ is a poset (this is covered in the text by Adámek and Rosicky). So the answer to the first question is: only when $C$ is an algebraic lattice.

The category of internal categories in an lfp category is again lfp. (Because the category of internal categories will be monadic over the category of internal graphs, and the latter is lfp.) However, a poset won't have any interesting internal categories.

Comment: Thanks Todd.  I think this answers my question about CHU spaces because, according to Abramsky, CHU can be constructed as a subcategory of a dagger category which is not an algebraic latice....I think...I have to look again.  I am interested in FdHilb, specifically as to whether or not it is lfp, and I think your answer indicates that FdHilb is not lfp.  Interesting result.  Thanks again.  Correct me if I have this wrong.

Comment: @BenSprott: you said everything right. Neither CHU nor FdHilb nor Hilb is lfp, since each of these is self-dual. However, just in case it is of interest to you, the category of Hilbert spaces and linear contractions is ($\omega_1$-)accessible.