# Hosting Category Theory in a "universe" that is non-LFP

Tags: ct.category-theory, foundations

WHen I did my MSc, I was trained by a very talented topologist.  I had a passion for the subject before and since.  Now I am interested in category theory, but I seem to be very interested in the presentation and setting of the theory of categories.  In particular, I was very excited to find that we can have internal categories in a [monoidal category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category+in+a+monoidal+category).  Furthermore, I was even more excited to know that the category of internal categories in a monoidal category cannot be locally finitely presentable.  We know that TOP is non-LFP.  So, it seems that I wanted to reason about categories the way topologists reason about spaces: continuously.  I believe you can have concepts like idealization of structure where the finitely presentable objects in your non-LFP universe are the idealized concepts and everything else is the connective tissue.  There is the possibility of approximation of structure, where the compact elements from domain theory abstract up to categories themselves and this is only possible when your background is non-LFP....

My question is, naturally, a bit open: do we know for sure what benefits we get from setting Category theory in a non-LFP background (like the category of internal cats in a monoidal cat)?  What are the drawbacks?

Comment: What you say is surely false. The category of internal categories in $\mathbf{Set}$, a.k.a. the category of small categories, is in fact locally finitely presentable.

Comment: "To reason about categories the way topologists reason about spaces: continuously" is an admirable thing to do, indeed I'm trying to [do it myself](http://paultaylor.eu/ASD), but I don't see why not being LFP should be the principal issue.

Comment: Paul,  thanks for the comment.  I am not exactly sure why I have settled on this property either, except for some vague notions I "learned" about Domain theory.  The reasons I give in the post are some of my desires and they seem to be related to the property of LFP.  I wish I could spell it out better....

Comment: Zhen, I think you might be right, because I was talking about internal categories in a dagger symmetric monoidal category, namely something like FdHilb.  I am pretty sure in FdHilb, the cat of internal cats is non-LFP [as in here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141360/lfp-property-for-dagger-symmetric-monoidal-categories-and-their-internal-categor).  I should have been more specific.